# Prove $\sum_{i=0}^{n}\left(x_{i}^{n}\prod_{0\leq k\leq n}^{k\neq i}\frac{x-x_k}{x_i-x_k}\right)=x^n$

Tags: polynomials, roots, summation

Suppose $x_0$ , $x_1$ , $x_2$ , ... , $x_n$ are distinct real numbers , prove that :

$$
\large{\displaystyle{\sum_{i=0}^{n}
\left(
x_{i}^{n}\prod_{\substack{0\leq k\leq n \\ k\neq i }}\frac{x-x_k}{x_i-x_k}
\right)=x^n}}
$$

I have no ideas to do this question

Comment: yes, i am sorry !That is typing error! The question correct now

Comment: Both sides are polynomials of degree $\le n$ in $x$. Hence they are equal, if they are equal at $n+1$ disticnt points. Check equality at $x = x_j$, $0 \le j \le n$.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's simply Lagrange's polynomial interpolation formula for the values of the polynomial $x^n$. Since there are $n+1$ data points, the two polynomials coincide.

Comment: also re. to answer to <http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1836535/prove-lagrange-form-of-interpolation-for-xj>